# calculating average of std_logic_vector variables in a function

Tags: function, package, average

I'm trying to write two package functions in VHDL that average two and four 8-bit std_logic_vector input signals.  When I implement the following avgtwo code, I get an answer 2x larger than expected in my simulation.  It's like the return operation 'sum(sum'high downto 1)' is not taking the upper 8 bits of sum... What am I missing?

```
    library IEEE;
    use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;
    use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.all;
    use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

    package my_package is
        function avgtwo(v1, v2 : std_logic_vector) return std_logic_vector;
        function avgfour(v1, v2, v3, v4 : std_logic_vector) return std_logic_vector;
    end my_package;

    package body my_package is
        function avgtwo
        (
            v1, v2 : std_logic_vector
        )
        return std_logic_vector is
        variable sum : std_logic_vector(v1'high+1 downto 0) := (others => '0');
        begin
            sum := std_logic_vector(unsigned(v1)) + std_logic_vector(unsigned(v2));
            return sum(sum'high downto 1);
        end function avgtwo;


        function avgfour
        (
            v1, v2, v3, v4 : std_logic_vector
        )
        return std_logic_vector is
        variable sum : std_logic_vector(v1'high+2 downto 0) := (others => '0');
        begin
            sum := std_logic_vector(unsigned(v1)) + std_logic_vector(unsigned(v2)) + std_logic_vector(unsigned(v3)) + std_logic_vector(unsigned(v4));
            return sum(sum'high downto 2);
        end function avgfour;

    end my_package;
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what I was doing wrong.  You have to make sure you are adding two std_logic_vectors of the same size as the receiving variable.  So I edited the summation lines as follows:

In the 'avgtwo' function:

```
sum := std_logic_vector(unsigned('0' & v1)) + std_logic_vector(unsigned('0' & v2));
```

Similar for the avgfour function - but use "00" instead of '0'.